# How to scrape Covid-19 dynamic data from the graph?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this url : https://covidestim.org/us

to get the Effective reproduction number (Rt)
from each state, but i am trying to make a dataset of all values with time.

[image]

for each state the data is on the graph, but i need to hover over to get.

[image]

[image]

The problem with this method is the performance.
so, i have looked around the network tab, there are some console logs and GET requests but those are only related to the counties in one state (not the state itself) for example :
Hovering a state a country inside is displayed with the actual data in the array.

[image]

NOTE: downloading the dataset using the [link](https://covidestim.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/latest/state/estimates.csv) in the page doesn't return accurate data like the one in the website,

Comment: They have rt number for every single date for 1 state. Do you wanna scrape all of them ? or is there any specific date as well ?

Comment: yes i want to scrape them all, and form a dataset of time, rt_num

Comment: @cruisepandey there also summary.pack.gz in the requests while making GET request to only specific location for example : Montana : https://covidestim.org/us/MT